# Assigning a string variable to an unsigned char variable

Tags: c++, arrays, hex

Assume I have a string s that represents a hex value:

```
string s="0x80";
```

I want to assign the value of s to v, where v is defined as:

```
unsigned char v;
```

What is the simplest way of doing it?

---

Why do I need it? Because in [here](http://www.partow.net/programming/bloomfilter/index.html), a bloom filter is represented as a vector of unsigned char where each char represents 8 bits. I want to access each char, perform some computation on it, and then store it back in a compatible form. Also, when I print each element of the vector (which is of type unsigned char) it appears in a hex form, e.g. 3a, 98, etc.

Comment: Why are strings involved at all? "vector of unsigned char" is not a string (just use it directly)

Comment: Assuming the number is always going to fit in an unsigned char, `v = std::stoul(s, nullptr, 16);` [Documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul)

Comment: But it sounds more like you're *actually* asking how to convert a number to a hex string... or have a fundamental misunderstanding of how numbers are stored in a computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Construct a `std::istringstream` from the string.
2. Extract the number from the `istringstream` by indicating that the stream contains data in hex format.
3. Assign the number to a `char`.

---

```
std::string s="0x80";
std::istringstream str(s);
int num;
str >> std::hex >> num;

unsigned char v = num;
```

Comment: note this will ignore any invalid characters, e.g. `"0x8G"` will parse successfully

Answer (score 4):

Convert string to integer:

```
unsigned char num = std::stoi(s, nullptr, 0);
```

Comment: Shouldn't pass `nullptr` as the second parameter or the function will silently ignore some errors